c++ metaprogramming: 'nullptr' vs '0' as a default paramater for "enable_if<bool>::type* = [x]"
I'm new to metaprogramming, and I've encountered a certain behavior I couldn't understand.
It seems that you can use '0' as a default-function-parameter, but not as a default-template-parameter. and I don't understand why.
I boiled down my code to this:
#include <iostream>     // cout, endl

using namespace std;


void Foo1(typename enable_if<true>::type* = nullptr)    // works
{
    cout << "Foo1" << endl;
}

template <typename enable_if<true>::type* = nullptr>    // works
void Foo2()
{
    cout << "Foo2" << endl;
}

void Foo3(typename enable_if<true>::type* = 0)  // works
{
    cout << "Foo3" << endl;
}

// argument of type "int" is incompatible with template parameter
// of type "void *"
template <typename enable_if<true>::type* = 0>  // doesn't work
void Foo4()
{
    cout << "Foo4" << endl;
}

void Foo4() // overloading 'Foo4()' to make compilation possible
{
    cout << "Foo4: substitution failure" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    Foo1();
    Foo2();
    Foo3();
    Foo4();

    return 0;
}

output:
Foo1
Foo2
Foo3
Foo4: substitution failure

disabling the second definition of 'Foo4' yields the following errors and notes:
error: no matching function for call to ‘Foo4()’
   41 |         Foo4();
      |         ~~~~^~
note: candidate: ‘template<std::enable_if<true, void>::type* <anonymous> > void Foo4()’
   25 | void Foo4()
      |      ^~~~
note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
error: could not convert template argument ‘0’ from ‘int’ to ‘std::enable_if<true, void>::type*’ {aka ‘void*’}
   24 | template <typename enable_if<true>::type* = 0>  // doesn't work
      |                                             ^

Because the available information at compile time is identical for both 'Foo3' and 'Foo4' - I was expecting for both of them to act the same.
So why does the deduction only fail in 'Foo4' (i.e. only for template-parameter)?

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

SFINEA with enable_if is history lesson. If you're a starter, get used to template constraints through the C++20 concepts.


It seems that you can use '0' as a default-function-parameter, but not as a default-template-parameter. and I don't understand why.

The reason is simple. When calling Foo4 and thus causing an implicit instantiation of the function template, the default argument 0 is substituted as if you had written Foo4<0>, with the following effect:

If type deduction has not yet failed, then all uses of template parameters in the function type are replaced with the corresponding deduced or default argument values.
If the substitution results in an invalid type, as described above, type deduction fails.

- [temp.deduct.general] p5
You produce an invalid type because template arguments need to be converted constant expressions (see [temp.arg.nontype] p2), and [expr.const] p13.8 says that for null pointer conversions, only conversions from std::nullptr_t, not from zero-literals are allowed.
Foo3 is different because default function arguments aren't subject to these strict rules, so = 0 is just another null pointer conversion.

Well, the compiler is pretty explicit about what's happening:

conversion from 'int' to 'std::enable_if<true, void>::type*' {aka 'void*'} > in a converted constant expression
24 | template <typename enable_if::type* = 0>  // doesn't work

Non-type template parameters are exclusively compile-time. That is not the case for default function arguments, which are evaluated at call site, which might also involve runtime.
demo
EDIT: Here is a list of possible conversions: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constant_expression
As you can see int->void* is absent on that list.

I'm not sure if this is a satisfactory answer, but it's simply a language rule ([temp.arg.nontype]p2):

If T [= the template parameter] is not a class type and A [= the template argument] is not a braced-init-list, A shall be a converted constant expression ([expr.const]) of type T; the value of P is A (as converted).

Moreover, converted constant expressions are defined to "contain only [...] null pointer conversions from std​::​nullptr_t", but not from the literal 0.
You're right that general pointer conversions ([conv.ptr]) allow conversions from all "null pointer constants", which include integer literals, but for template arguments this is just not allowed.
